# postgresql bitwise XOR operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, xor

So i want to XOR on hexadecimal
so i do this

```
select X'4e20' # X'4521'; --the output is 0000101100000001
```

but the thing is i wanna do XOR binary with hexa or integer with hexa or integer with binary, so i try to do this

```
select X(select to_hex(6700::bit(16))) # X'4F21';
```

this query will produce error result

```
[Err] ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 2: select X(select to_hex(6700::bit(16))) # ...
```

So how can i do this that? and is it possible to xor an Ascii on postgresql?
and i want to know how to :

1.convert binary to integer

2.convert hexa to binary vice versa

3.convert hexa to integer

4.conver ascii to integer

this is Bit String Functions and Operators official from postgresql
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-bitstring.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output to be a `bit` value, you should cast the `integer` to `bit`:

```
test=> SELECT 6700::bit(16) # X'4F21';

     ?column?     
------------------
 0101010100001101
(1 row)
```